# Go Channel writes data beyond it's capacity

Tags: go, channel

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func write(ch chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println("avaliable", i)
        ch <- i
        fmt.Println("successfully wrote", i, "to ch")
    }

    close(ch)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    go write(ch)

    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println("read value", v, "from ch")
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
avaliable 0
successfully wrote 0 to ch
avaliable 1
read value 0 from ch
read value 1 from ch
successfully wrote 1 to ch
avaliable 2
successfully wrote 2 to ch
avaliable 3
read value 2 from ch
read value 3 from ch
successfully wrote 3 to ch
avaliable 4
successfully wrote 4 to ch
read value 4 from ch
```

Since this is a unbuffered channel it should have blocked as soon as data is written into it until another goroutine reads from the same channel. But it accepts data beyond it's capacity.

**Intended Behavior**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func write(ch chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println("avaliable", i)
        ch <- i
        fmt.Println("successfully wrote", i, "to ch")
    }

    close(ch)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    go write(ch)

    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println("read value", v, "from ch")

        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
avaliable 0
read value 0 from ch
successfully wrote 0 to ch
avaliable 1
read value 1 from ch
successfully wrote 1 to ch
avaliable 2
read value 2 from ch
successfully wrote 2 to ch
avaliable 3
read value 3 from ch
successfully wrote 3 to ch
avaliable 4
read value 4 from ch
successfully wrote 4 to ch
```

If some timers are placed throughout the code so that the main goroutine is blocked before each iteration it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't infer anything from your output, because there is no ordering guarantee between the "read value" and "successfully wrote" Printfs executing. (There is one between the "available" Printf, which occurs before the channel send, and the "read value" Printf, which occurs after the corresponding channel receive, and you can see that that ordering is never violated in your output).

The channel isn't buffering anything, because it has no buffer; it's just that the two different goroutines run in an indeterminate order after the channel send completes. Sometimes the sending side gets to go first and prints the "successfully wrote" message, and sometimes the receiving side gets to go first and prints the "read value" message. Neither one ever "gets ahead" by more than one value, because they're still fully synchronized on the channel send; they're just racing to print their status messages immediately after.

When you add the Sleep calls to main, it just so happens to make it so that the goroutine running `write` will always be blocked on waiting to send the next value, while the one running `main` blocks on the call to `Sleep`. When the timer expires, the main goroutine wakes up, and immediately finds that it has something waiting for it on the channel, grabs it, and goes back to sleep, and then the `write` goroutine gets woken up. By slowing things down you've gotten the scheduler to run things in a consistent order (although it's still partly a matter of luck); without the sleeps, with everything running as fast as it can, the result is apparently random.

Answer (score 1):

If that were the case, the output of the "sleeping" version would be even more chaotic.

You cannot expect a coherent output from two independent threads even if they are synchronized at some point.

Comment: it is possible to get coherent (and consistent) output of syncrhonized "threads". https://go.dev/play/p/Waf4JKw2eAq You cant concurrently write to a resource and expect a deterministic order, indeed.